# PHPUnit how to avoid "OutOfRangeException" in __construct()

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a PHP unit that looks like this:

```
class Challenge1Test extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider invalidConstructorValues
     */
    public function test_throws_exception_for_initial_value(int $value): void
    {
        $this->expectException(\OutOfRangeException::class);
        new ImmutableWeekDay($value);
    }
//...
}
```

It's testing the __construct() of my class and if the value is out of range is gives back OutOfRangeException. I am testing with data that is expected to throw that error.

```
/**
 * @throws \OutOfRangeException
 */
public function __construct(int $value)
{
    $this->value = $value;
}
```

The above gives the expected error on bad data entry.

I am trying to pass the test so I am only initializing that var when it meets the range requirement

```
/**
 * @throws \OutOfRangeException
 */
public function __construct(int $value)
{
    $refl = new \ReflectionClass($this);

    $this->value = null;

    foreach($refl->getConstants() as $k=> $v){
        if ($v = $value){
            $this->value = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

But I still get the out of range exception on bad data. Is there a way in my controller without modifying the test to pass it?

Link to my php sandbox code here:
https://phpsandbox.io/n/old-term-kkap-0hqmq?files=%2Fsrc%2FChallenge1%2FImmutableWeekDay.php

Answer (score 0):

In this test, the test_throws_exception_for_initial_value is missing
at least the condition that use the exception, but I would check if
the $value of function calls is the correct object. I thing it is
correctly.

```
public function test_throws_exception_for_initial_value(int $value): void
{
    $act = (Object) new ImmutableWeekDay($value);
    $this->assertIsObject($act);

}
```

However, in the constructor I would check if the $value passed in the call is in the correct range.

```
public function __construct(int $value)
{
    $this->value = null;

    $wynik = -1;
    $a = new \ReflectionClass($this);
    foreach ($a->getConstants() as $v){
        $wynik = $v;
    }
    if ($value >= 0 && $value <= $wynik)
        $this->value = $value;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).